# After combine the vectors into matrix, how to keep the original attribute of vector (not changed)

Tags: r, vector

below R code show an example about vectors combination, after that, the attribute of vector "c" changed to character. how to make it still keep attribute as numeric?

```
a='aa';b='bb';c=c(1,2,3,4,5)
dd=data.table(cbind(a,b,c));dd;class(dd);class(a);class(b);typeof(dd$c)
```

running result as below:

```
> a='aa';b='bb';c=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> dd=data.table(cbind(a,b,c));dd;class(dd);class(a);class(b);typeof(dd$c)
    a  b c
1: aa bb 1
2: aa bb 2
3: aa bb 3
4: aa bb 4
5: aa bb 5
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
```

see typeof(dd$c) has been changed to "character" not numeric any more. how to keep it's original attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because `cbind` converts to `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class.  If there is a single `character` element, it converts the whole matrix to `character`.  It is better to do

```
data.table(a, b, c)
```